# Magento 2: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after re-enabling cache

Tags: magento, caching, magento2

Before this `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, I was trying to resolve another error below on Varnish. Got the Varnish error a few days ago immediately after disabling all cache via Magento admin.

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed
Guru Meditation:
XID:
Varnish cache server
```

I executed `sudo bin/magento-cli cache:enable` to re-enable cache and reset the VM on Google Cloud Platform. That seemed to have solved it.

Unfortunately, the redirect error showed up. I get the error when trying to access Magento admin and front-end via URL. Tried clearing the cookies and cache (in Chrome browser) but it still persists. Using the IP address, I'm only able to access the front-end, not admin.

[image]

I've also run `sudo bin/magento-cli indexer:reindex` but the outcome is the same.

Does this have anything to re-enabling the cache? Or it's related to some configurations on Varnish itself?

Comment: You're having a HTTP 302 loop on all URLs, are you forwarding the x-forwarded-for headers correctly in the VCL?

Comment: I tried to search in default.vcl and magento.vcl in /opt/bitnami/varnish/etc/varnish but couldn't find x-forwarded-for header in both files. Should I add a line somewhere?